# About Implicit Function Theorem and Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, implicit-function-theorem

I am studying the meaning of the multiplier in Lagrange Multiplier Method and got the following question. I tried it myself, but I am not sure if it is correct. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me check. In order to state the question, we need some background information first:

***Background Information***

> **Theorem**$\space\space\space\space$ Let $f$ and $h$ be $C^1$ functions of two variables. For any field value of the parameter $a$, let $(x^*(a), y^*(a))$ be the solution of the following maximization problem
> \begin{equation}
> Max\space\space\space\space f(x, y)\\
> \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space s.t.\space\space\space\space h(x, y) = a
> \end{equation}
> with corresponding multiplier $\mu^*(a)$. Suppose that $x^*$, $y^*$, and $\mu^*$ are $C^1$ functions of $a$ and that NDCQ holds at $(x^*(a), y^*(a), \mu^*(a))$. Then,
> \begin{equation}
> \mu^*(a) = \frac{d}{da}f(x^*(a),y^*(a)).
> \end{equation}

***Question***

> Use the Implicit Function Theorem to write out a specific inequality which would guarantee the validity of the assumption in the above theorem that the solution $(x(a), y(a))$ of the maximization problem depends smoothly on $a$.

***My Attempt***

> Consider the maximization problem as in the above theorem:
> \begin{equation}
> Max\space\space\space\space f(x, y)\\
> \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space s.t.\space\space\space\space h^*(x, y; a) \equiv h(x, y) - a = 0.
> \end{equation}
> Assume that the constraint qualification holds at $(x^*(a), y^*(a))$, the solution to the maximization problem:
> \begin{equation}
> \nabla h^*(x, y; a) = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{\partial h^*}{\partial x}(x^*(a), y^*(a); a)\\
> \frac{\partial h^*}{\partial y}(x^*(a), y^*(a); a).
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation}
> Form the Lagrangian:
> \begin{equation}
> L(x, y, \mu; a) = f(x, y, ;a) - \mu h^*(x, y; a).
> \end{equation}
> The constrained maximizer $(x^*(a), y^*(a))$ must satisfy the F.O.C.s:
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}(x, y, \mu; a) = 0\\
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}(x, y, \mu; a) = 0\\
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu}(x, y, \mu; a) = 0,
> \end{equation}
> a system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns.
> By the Implicit Function Theorem, we need the matrix
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial \mu}\\
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial \mu}\\
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial \mu} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial \mu} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \mu^2}
> \end{pmatrix} = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial \mu}\\
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial \mu}\\
> \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x \partial \mu} & \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial y \partial \mu} & 0
> \end{pmatrix},
> \end{equation}
> which is the Hessian matrix $D^2L$ of the Lagrangian, to be nonsingular. Therefore, the inequality we are looking for is that
> \begin{equation}
> det(D^2L) \neq 0.
> \end{equation}

Could someone please help me check if this is correct? Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What is NDCQ? ${}{}$

Comment: @AShrike NDCQ is Non-Degenerate Constraint Qualification. Please refer to this link "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754105/the-intuition-of-non-degenerate-constraint-qualification-and-its-application-whe" for details. (The NDCQ is stated in a Theorem in the Background Information.)

Comment: No, NDCQ is equivalent to LICQ, and It does not mean that the Hessian of the Lagrangian is nonsingular. The Implicit function theorem allows us to see that $(x(a),y(a))$ is differentiable. So, it is only necessary to use the Chain Rule to differentiate the objective function $f(x(a),y(a))$